# Binary floating point precision question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, computer-science

How do we know what is the degree of precision of an 8 bit floating point number and what fraction of the possible value of the number might it vary by and still
be represented by the same bits in my floating point 8-bit memory?

What we written in class and I can't seem to understand is:

$$1.00111011 - 1.00111001 \implies 2\times 2^{-7} \text{precision}$$

Can somebody explain what we just did, and what is the general procedure for such tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following `C` program:

```
double x = 1.00111011;
double y = 1.00111001;

printf("\n0x%llx", *((long long int*) & x));
printf("\n0x%llx", *((long long int*) & y));
```

It will show that both 8-byte floating-point numbers in fact do not have the same byte representation:

```
0x3ff0048c08e251c4
0x3ff0048bee0a5f2a
```

You can get a visual explanation by using an [IEEE 754 calculator](http://weitz.de/ieee/).

If you run the same experiment with single-precision 4-byte *float* variables, you get:

```
0x3f802460
0x3f80245f
```

In this case, the difference is just one bit.
The difference of the two numbers is the smallest one you can express with this data type. So, you probably tried to reduce the second number as far as possible without reaching zero difference.

You can find a *float* calculator [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).